# Request time-out in Quickfix ??

Tags: quickfix

is there anyway to set request time-out while sending message from initiator ??

we had a issue where we got late reply from acceptor and application went in not responsive mode. issue can be with network delay or etc. but I think it will be good if we can set time-out option here.

Seeing with Application call back didn't find anything .

I want to set time-out option with `SendToTarget` API,,

any suggestion

Comment: Was it *really* a late reply, or were you perhaps accidentally blocking the callback thread for too long?  You must make sure you don't perform time-expensive operations inside the MessageCracker callbacks.

Comment: no we are not performing time expensive operation in callback.. yes it's a late reply only...as acceptor is not very stable as of now also we are not controlling acceptor part... we know root problem with acceptor side but as a initiator we want to make sure nothing blocks us.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add **CheckLatency** and **MaxLatency** in your config file and confirmed ?

> CheckLatency   If set to Y, messages must be received from the counterparty within a defined number of seconds (see MaxLatency). It is useful to turn this off if a system uses localtime for it's timestamps instead of GMT.
>
> MaxLatency     If CheckLatency is set to Y, this defines the number of seconds latency allowed for a message to be processed. Default is 120.  positive integer

Comment: tried with CheckLatency and Max Latency but it looks like quick-fix is not using these tags or implementation is missing... did you tried latency configuration ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem using QuickFix /n

Looking at the source code for version 1.4 the section that reads those settings from the configuration file is commented out and replaced with hard coded default values.

```
// FIXME to get from config if available
session.MaxLatency = 120;
session.CheckLatency = true;
```